# Alternative to ->operator()

Tags: c++, pointers, overloading, operator-keyword

Is there a nicer syntax than calling `objp->operator()(x, y, z)` if `objp` is a pointer? `&objp(x, y, z)` does not work. Because of all the symbols, this is hard to Google. Sorry of this is silly.

Comment: Yes, it's ugly, but at least it's very obvious what you're doing with that line of code.  I prefer that syntax over any of the alternatives because I can see right away what's happening.  For something like `(*objp)(x,y,z)` I have to stop and think about it for a few seconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `(*objp)(x, y, z);` as an alternative.

Answer (score 8):

`(*objp)(x, y, z);` would be the obvious alternative. I'm not sure if you consider that nicer or not though.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in two lines;

```
MyType&  functorRef  = *objp;   // Use the appropriate type name.
functorRef(x, y, z);
```

Or in C++11 you can use auto.

```
auto&  functorRef  = *objp;
functorRef(x, y, z);
```